# Password Protect Access Database from Edits

Tags: microsoft-access-2010

I'm familiar with how to encrypt an Access database with a password (requiring a password to view data). Is there a way to allow data *viewing* w/o a password, but requiring one for *editing* the database? I'm imagining something similar to the Protect Worksheet feature in Excel. I'm using Access 2010.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can directly. If I understand your question, you want the SQL style permission of (deny_datawriter and deny_datareader etc. per user).

You can possibly achieve the same via permissions (although it does depend on your situation).

Right click the access file, and under the security tab set the permissions (read/write/full control etc). Or, you could even set this up as groups if it's for many people/user types. Then you just set the appropriate groups permission.

It may require you moving this file to a shared location for this to work though (which may not be an option for you).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using one of the new file formats in Access 2010 (.accdb, .accde, .accdc, .accdr), user-level security (the Access way to prevent users from being able to edit the database) is not available. (https://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/what-happened-to-user-level-security-HA010342116.aspx)

From a purely theoretical standpoint, if you are distributing an Access database file to a user, any user that can view the database could reconstruct the database and modify the new version of the database.

If you mean to allow users to access data remotely, and grant some users the ability to modify that data, you may be looking for a more fully-featured RDBMS such as an SQL server, and you might look into Microsoft SQL server, MySQL, or PostgreSQL.